# WPF Custom Window Resize Issue

Tags: c#, wpf, resize

I have exactly the same problem like this [one](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f984d743-6669-4192-8e0d-d586818e9349/wpf-custom-window-resizing?forum=wpf)

Everything is fine, but when i resize from `West to East` or `North to South`, the `East/South` side of the windows is kinda shaky, and it doesn't look very good.

As i can see this post is from long, long time ago, and still there is no valid answer in it, i was looking around, but couldn't find anything, anyone can tell me if this issue is fixed and where i can find the solution?

**[xaml]:**

```
<ControlTemplate>
    <!-- MainGrid -->
    <Grid x:Name="PART_MainGrid">
        <!-- MainGrid.Rows -->
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" x:Name="PART_MainGridRow0" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" x:Name="PART_MainGridRow1" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" x:Name="PART_MainGridRow2" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" x:Name="PART_MainGridRow3" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" x:Name="PART_MainGridRow4" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <!-- MainGrid.Columns -->
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" x:Name="PART_MainGridCol0"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" x:Name="PART_MainGridCol1"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" x:Name="PART_MainGridCol2"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" x:Name="PART_MainGridCol3"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" x:Name="PART_MainGridCol4"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!-- MainGrid.ShadowBorders -->
        <Border x:Name="PART_ShadowBorderWest"      Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="3"/>
        <Border x:Name="PART_ShadowBorderNorth"     Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>            
        <Border x:Name="PART_ShadowBorderEast"      Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4" Grid.RowSpan="3"/>
        <Border x:Name="PART_ShadowBorderSouth"     Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>
        <Border x:Name="PART_ShadowBorderNorthWest" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <Border x:Name="PART_ShadowBorderNorthEast" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4"/>
        <Border x:Name="PART_ShadowBorderSouthEast" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="4"/>                
        <Border x:Name="PART_ShadowBorderSouthWest" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <!-- MainGrid.Borders -->
        <Border x:Name="PART_BorderWest"      Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Border x:Name="PART_BorderNorth"     Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"/>
        <Border x:Name="PART_BorderEast"      Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3"/>
        <Border x:Name="PART_BorderSouth"     Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2"/>
        <Border x:Name="PART_BorderNorthWest" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Border x:Name="PART_BorderNorthEast" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3"/>
        <Border x:Name="PART_BorderSouthEast" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3">                
        <Border x:Name="PART_BorderSouthWest" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"/>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

**[c#]:**

```
   // Global Variable
   private Point cursorOffset;
   #region All Resize Events and Functions
        public void AddNorthWestResizeEvents(FrameworkElement element)
        {
            if (element == null)
                return;

            element.MouseEnter += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (WindowState != WindowState.Maximized && ResizeMode == ResizeMode.CanResize)
                    element.Cursor = Cursors.SizeNWSE;
                else
                    element.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
            };

            element.MouseLeftButtonDown += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (WindowState != WindowState.Maximized && ResizeMode == ResizeMode.CanResize)
                {
                    Point cursorLocation = e.GetPosition(this);

                    cursorOffset.X = cursorLocation.X;
                    cursorOffset.Y = cursorLocation.Y;

                    element.CaptureMouse();
                }
            };

            element.MouseMove += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (WindowState != WindowState.Maximized && element.IsMouseCaptured && ResizeMode == ResizeMode.CanResize)
                {
                    Point cursorLocation = e.GetPosition(this);

                    double nHorizontalChange = (cursorLocation.X - cursorOffset.X);
                    double nVerticalChange = (cursorLocation.Y - cursorOffset.Y);

                    if (Width - nHorizontalChange > MinWidth)
                    {
                        Left += nHorizontalChange;
                        Width -= nHorizontalChange;
                    }
                    if (Height - nVerticalChange > MinHeight)
                    {
                        Top += nVerticalChange;
                        Height -= nVerticalChange;
                    }
                }
            };

            element.MouseLeftButtonUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(ReleaseMouseCapture);
        }
        public void AddNorthResizeEvents(FrameworkElement element)
        {
            if (element == null)
                return;

            element.MouseEnter += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (WindowState != WindowState.Maximized && ResizeMode == ResizeMode.CanResize)
                    element.Cursor = Cursors.SizeNS;
                else
                    element.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
            };

            element.MouseLeftButtonDown += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (WindowState != WindowState.Maximized && ResizeMode == ResizeMode.CanResize)
                {
                    Point cursorLocation = e.GetPosition(this);

                    cursorOffset.Y = cursorLocation.Y;

                    element.CaptureMouse();
                }
            };

            element.MouseMove += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (WindowState != WindowState.Maximized && element.IsMouseCaptured && ResizeMode == ResizeMode.CanResize)
                {
                    Point cursorLocation = e.GetPosition(this);

                    double nHorizontalChange = (cursorLocation.X - cursorOffset.X);
                    double nVerticalChange = (cursorLocation.Y - cursorOffset.Y);

                    if (Height - nVerticalChange > MinHeight)
                    {
                        Top += nVerticalChange;
                        Height -= nVerticalChange;
                    }
                }
            };

            element.MouseLeftButtonUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(ReleaseMouseCapture);
        }
        public void AddNorthEastResizeEvents(FrameworkElement element)
        {
            if (element == null)
                return;

            element.MouseEnter += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (WindowState != WindowState.Maximized && ResizeMode == ResizeMode.CanResize)
                    element.Cursor = Cursors.SizeNESW;
                else
                    element.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
            };

            element.MouseLeftButtonDown += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (WindowState != WindowState.Maximized && ResizeMode == ResizeMode.CanResize)
                {
                    Point cursorLocation = e.GetPosition(this);

                    cursorOffset.X = (Width - cursorLocation.X);
                    cursorOffset.Y = cursorLocation.Y;

                    element.CaptureMouse();
                }
            };

            element.MouseMove += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (WindowState != WindowState.Maximized && element.IsMouseCaptured && ResizeMode == ResizeMode.CanResize)
                {
                    Point cursorLocation = e.GetPosition(this);

                    double nHorizontalChange = (cursorLocation.X - cursorOffset.X);
                    double pHorizontalChange = (cursorLocation.X + cursorOffset.X);
                    double nVerticalChange = (cursorLocation.Y - cursorOffset.Y);
                    double pVerticalChange = (cursorLocation.Y + cursorOffset.Y);

                    if (pHorizontalChange > MinWidth)
                        Width = pHorizontalChange;
                    if (Height - nVerticalChange > MinHeight)
                    {
                        Top += nVerticalChange;
                        Height -= nVerticalChange;
                    }
                }
            };

            element.MouseLeftButtonUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(ReleaseMouseCapture);
        }
        public void AddEastResizeEvents(FrameworkElement element)
        {
            if (element == null)
                return;

            element.MouseEnter += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (WindowState != WindowState.Maximized && ResizeMode == ResizeMode.CanResize)
                    element.Cursor = Cursors.SizeWE;
                else
                    element.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
            };

            element.MouseLeftButtonDown += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (WindowState != WindowState.Maximized && ResizeMode == ResizeMode.CanResize)
                {
                    Point cursorLocation = e.GetPosition(this);

                    cursorOffset.X = (Width - cursorLocation.X);

                    element.CaptureMouse();
                }
            };

            element.MouseMove += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (WindowState != WindowState.Maximized && element.IsMouseCaptured && ResizeMode == ResizeMode.CanResize)
                {
                    Point cursorLocation = e.GetPosition(this);

                    double pHorizontalChange = (cursorLocation.X + cursorOffset.X);

                    if (pHorizontalChange > MinWidth)
                        Width = pHorizontalChange;
                }
            };

            element.MouseLeftButtonUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(ReleaseMouseCapture);
        }
        public void AddSouthEastResizeEvents(FrameworkElement element)
        {
            if (element == null)
                return;

            element.MouseEnter += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (WindowState != WindowState.Maximized && ResizeMode == ResizeMode.CanResize)
                    element.Cursor = Cursors.SizeNWSE;
                else
                    element.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
            };

            element.MouseLeftButtonDown += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (WindowState != WindowState.Maximized && ResizeMode == ResizeMode.CanResize)
                {
                    Point cursorLocation = e.GetPosition(this);

                    cursorOffset.X = (Width - cursorLocation.X);
                    cursorOffset.Y = (Height - cursorLocation.Y);

                    element.CaptureMouse();
                }
            };

            element.MouseMove += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (WindowState != WindowState.Maximized && element.IsMouseCaptured && ResizeMode == ResizeMode.CanResize)
                {
                    Point cursorLocation = e.GetPosition(this);

                    double pHorizontalChange = (cursorLocation.X + cursorOffset.X);
                    double pVerticalChange = (cursorLocation.Y + cursorOffset.Y);

                    if (pHorizontalChange > MinWidth)
                        Width = pHorizontalChange;
                    if (pVerticalChange > MinHeight)
                        Height = pVerticalChange;
                }
            };

            element.MouseLeftButtonUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(ReleaseMouseCapture);
        }
        public void AddSouthResizeEvents(FrameworkElement element)
        {
            if (element == null)
                return;

            element.MouseEnter += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (WindowState != WindowState.Maximized && ResizeMode == ResizeMode.CanResize)
                    element.Cursor = Cursors.SizeNS;
                else
                    element.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
            };

            element.MouseLeftButtonDown += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (WindowState != WindowState.Maximized && ResizeMode == ResizeMode.CanResize)
                {
                    Point cursorLocation = e.GetPosition(this);

                    cursorOffset.Y = (Height - cursorLocation.Y);

                    element.CaptureMouse();
                }
            };

            element.MouseMove += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (WindowState != WindowState.Maximized && element.IsMouseCaptured && ResizeMode == ResizeMode.CanResize)
                {
                    Point cursorLocation = e.GetPosition(this);

                    double pVerticalChange = (cursorLocation.Y + cursorOffset.Y);

                    if (pVerticalChange > MinHeight)
                        Height = pVerticalChange;

                }
            };

            element.MouseLeftButtonUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(ReleaseMouseCapture);
        }
        public void AddSouthWestResizeEvents(FrameworkElement element)
        {
            if (element == null)
                return;

            element.MouseEnter += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (WindowState != WindowState.Maximized && ResizeMode == ResizeMode.CanResize)
                    element.Cursor = Cursors.SizeNESW;
                else
                    element.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
            };

            element.MouseLeftButtonDown += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (WindowState != WindowState.Maximized && ResizeMode == ResizeMode.CanResize)
                {
                    Point cursorLocation = e.GetPosition(this);

                    cursorOffset.X = cursorLocation.X;
                    cursorOffset.Y = (Height - cursorLocation.Y);

                    element.CaptureMouse();
                }
            };

            element.MouseMove += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (WindowState != WindowState.Maximized && element.IsMouseCaptured && ResizeMode == ResizeMode.CanResize)
                {
                    Point cursorLocation = e.GetPosition(this);

                    double nHorizontalChange = (cursorLocation.X - cursorOffset.X);
                    double pVerticalChange = (cursorLocation.Y + cursorOffset.Y);

                    if (Width - nHorizontalChange > MinWidth)
                    {
                        Left += nHorizontalChange;
                        Width -= nHorizontalChange;
                    }
                    if (pVerticalChange > MinHeight)
                        Height = pVerticalChange;
                }
            };

            element.MouseLeftButtonUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(ReleaseMouseCapture);
        }
        public void AddWestResizeEvents(FrameworkElement element)
        {
            if (element == null)
                return;

            element.MouseEnter += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (WindowState != WindowState.Maximized && ResizeMode == ResizeMode.CanResize)
                    element.Cursor = Cursors.SizeWE;
                else
                    element.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
            };

            element.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (WindowState != WindowState.Maximized && ResizeMode == ResizeMode.CanResize)
                {
                    Point cursorLocation = e.GetPosition(this);

                    cursorOffset.X = cursorLocation.X;

                    element.CaptureMouse();                    
                }
            };

            element.MouseMove += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (WindowState != WindowState.Maximized && element.IsMouseCaptured && ResizeMode == ResizeMode.CanResize)
                {
                    Point cursorLocation = e.GetPosition(this);

                    double nHorizontalChange = (cursorLocation.X - cursorOffset.X);

                    if (Width - nHorizontalChange > MinWidth)
                    {
                        Left += nHorizontalChange;
                        Width -= nHorizontalChange;
                    }
                }
            };

            element.MouseLeftButtonUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(ReleaseMouseCapture);
        }
```

Comment: If you'd like an answer, then please [show your relevant code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: There you go sir, i hope you can help me!

Comment: I gave your the ControlTemplate for xaml, which cannot be reduced more...
About the c# code, there is only 8 functions, which add listeners to the Borders from the ControlTemplate, its enough to read the first function and you will know what i am doing... about the code on other sites, i thought it would be too large for this post, i can rehost it here, its not a problem...

Comment: I add those handlers OnSourceInitialized, so those handlers will be added once, and will last forever... but i dont think thats a problem in my case, my code works good, but the visual behavior doesn't as i mentioned above and as the other user on MSForum has the same problem with flickering/shaking

Comment: What are you adding those handlers to? The window? Or to controls within the window?

Comment: To the controls i.e. Borders defined in the XAML within the window

Comment: Ok, think I might be starting to understand how it works now, but what are you trying to achieve? Is this a custom window with none of the usual chrome? Is your new grid simply supplying all the drag handles to resize it?

Comment: Yes its custom window with none of the usual chrome.
And the new Grid is the main content of the client area, on sides there are 2 types of borders, shadow and normal borders, and i have attached those MouseEvents through functions AddXXResizeEvents corresponding to the border that needs those events.

Comment: Then you are being too low level. You really don't need this level of complexity, instead see my answer below and let WPF do it for you.