# Launch MouseEnter event Image from XAML dictionnary with MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a template for a DataGrid located in a ResourceDictionary.

BlockStyles.xaml

```
<Style TargetType="DataGrid" x:Key="SearchExpGrid">
    <Setter Property="AlternatingRowBackground" Value="#4C87C6ff"/>
    <Setter Property="GridLinesVisibility" Value="None"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
    <Setter Property="HeadersVisibility" Value="Column"/>
    <Setter Property="CellStyle">
        <Setter.Value ... />
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="RowStyle">
        <Setter.Value ... />
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="ColumnHeaderStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Border 
                                x:Name="Border" Background="White" BorderBrush="#4C87C6" BorderThickness="1" >
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5,5" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                    <TextBlock 
                                        x:Name="TxtB"  Text="{Binding}"
                                        Foreground="#4C87C6" FontWeight="DemiBold" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    <Image Source="../Images/dropdown.png"
                                               Width="10" Height="10" Margin="5,0,5,0"
                                              MouseEnter="DropdownButton_MouseEnter"
                                              MouseLeave="DropdownButton_MouseLeave"
                                              MouseEnter="DropdownButton_Click"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#4C87C6"/>
                                    <Setter TargetName="TxtB" Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I always have an error because the function can't find it's definition.

I first implemented the function in the View file where the style is used but it doesn't work.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21708553/binding-referencing-method-to-xaml-wpf) method from StackOverflow using a resource class inheriting ResourceDictionnary but got the same error.

I then tried to use `ICommand` and `RelayCommand` to execute the function from the ViewModel but didn't got any result.

I also didn't find where I could add an EventHandler `ImgDropdownButton.MouseEnter += new MouseEventHandler(MouseEnter_DropdownButton);` using MVVM.

Is there a better solution for this kind of behaviour or if adding an EventHandler is the best solution, where sould be the best place to add it ?

Thanks in advance

### **Edit :**

I managed to handle the function using a code-behind file for my ResourceDictionary following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92100/is-it-possible-to-set-code-behind-a-resource-dictionary-in-wpf-for-event-handlin).

BlockStyles.xaml.cs

```cs
private void DropdownButton_MouseEnter(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Hand;
}

private void DropdownButton_MouseLeave(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Arrow;
}

private void DropdownButton_Click(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    //Function to show the popup
}
```

The MouseEnter and MouseLeave function are working, but I don't understand how to use the function to make my popup appear.

What I'm trying to do is that when I click on the Dropdown Image on the column header, I want to display a Popup, like an Excel one. This will allow the user to filter the columns values.

The file where my Grid and Popup are : (SearchExpView.xaml)

```
<Grid Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1">
    <searchcomponents:ExpListView x:Name="ExpDatagrid"
        DataContext="{Binding OExpListVM}" 
        Width="auto" Height="auto"/>
</Grid>

<Popup x:Name="PopupFiltre">
    PopupFiltre content
</Popup>
```

Definition of my Datagrid : (ExpListView.xaml)

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="ExpGrid" Style="{StaticResource SearchExpGrid}"
                  BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="#4C87C6"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                  MinHeight="200" Height="auto" Margin="10,10,0,0"
                  MinWidth="780" Width="auto"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding}" DataContext="{Binding tableExpertise.DefaultView}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="True" CanUserAddRows="False" IsReadOnly="True">
        <DataGrid.InputBindings>
            <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick"
                              Command="{Binding DataContext.OnRowDoubleClickedCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                              CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=ExpGrid, Path=CurrentItem}"/>
        </DataGrid.InputBindings>
        <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu Name="dgctxmenu">
                <Separator></Separator>
            </ContextMenu>
        </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

I'm looking for a way to be able to implement this popup fonction but I can't find out how to link everything together.

Comment: How is this related to MVVM? If you want to define an event handler, you *must* define it in the same class as the XAML markup.

Comment: Indeed, I managed to call a function creating a `.xaml.cs` file for my Dictionnary.

The problem I'm facing now is that I want the function to show a popup located in a different xaml file (the one using my Datagrid) but I think I should be putting the popup and the datagrid in the same file.

Comment: So what is your question then?

Comment: I edited my post to be as clear as possible.

Comment: So where is `PopupFiltre` defined? In an open window?

Comment: Yes, it is defined in my View that is displayed, just after the DataGrid.

Comment: So where is the resource dictionary supposed to look for it?

Comment: I would say in my dictionnary `.xaml.cs` file. The problem is that I can't get to send the information to display the Popup from here.

Comment: Is `inBlockStyles.xaml` a window or what is it?

Comment: My Window is `SearchExpView.xaml` (with the Datagrid and the Popup). My `Datagrid` component is defined in `ExpListView.xaml` and styled in `BlockStyles.xaml`, which is not a window. I want to make the Popup (in `SearchExpView.xaml`) visible by clicking on the dropdown button (defined in `BlockStyles.xaml`).

Comment: Then you should get a reference to this window somehow. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My Window is SearchExpView.xaml (with the Datagrid and the Popup). My Datagrid component is defined in ExpListView.xaml and styled in BlockStyles.xaml, which is not a window. I want to make the Popup (in SearchExpView.xaml) visible by clicking on the dropdown button (defined in BlockStyles.xaml)

Then you need to get a reference to the `Popup` in the window from the `ResourceDictionary` somehow.

You could for example use the static `Application.Current.Windows` property:

```
var window = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<SearchExpView>().FirstOrDefault();
if (window != null)
    window.PopupFiltre.IsOpen = true;
```

Also make sure that you make the `Popup` accessible from outside the `SearchExpView` class:

```
<Popup x:Name="PopupFiltre" x:FieldModifier="internal">
...
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks a lot !
I tried using static functions to update the Popup, but I wasn't aware of this way of doing it.
I didn't find this answer anywhere, so I'll update my post to be more clear about my issue and help other people find your answer.